# Create 3 sites under DefaultWebSite with https access having different port number

Tags: iis, virtual-directory

I have 3 sites(virtual directories) registered under the Default Web Site in IIS, those can access like below:

```
http://localhost/Site1
http://localhost/Site2
http://localhost/Site3
```

Currently I have one port number which is port 80. 
I need to setup those sites with https having different port numbers, like below:

```
https://demo.mydomain.com:5001/Site1
https://demo.mydomain.com:5002/Site2
https://demo.mydomain.com:5003/Site3
```

I am new to the IIS. Can someone please help me out with the approach to solve the above scenario?

Comment: First, ‘earn why Microsoft didn’t think you are building sites under a site, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

is the domain already pointing to your webserver or are you trying to achieve this on you development machine?

If the domain is already pointing to the server, you can do this IIS by adding bindings to your websites (in your case its the defaultwebsite). 
You can achieve this by right-clicking the website. Here you can see "Edit Bindings". You will have to add a binding foreach port. Just click on "add" and type in the right hostname (demo.mydomain.com) and the port. You can also choose a certificate here for the https connection.

If you are trying to achieve this on your dev machine, you will also have to add your hostname to the windows hosts-file. Under "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" add the line "127.0.0.1 demo.mydomain.com".

Jonathan

Comment: I did configure like you said. But there is a problem, we can access the all site with the same port number, like below: 

https://demo.mydomain.com:5001/Site1,     
https://demo.mydomain.com:5001/Site2,      
https://demo.mydomain.com:5001/Site3      

But, the expected behaviour is, different site different port number like: 

https://demo.mydomain.com:5001/Site1,      
https://demo.mydomain.com:5002/Site2,     
https://demo.mydomain.com:5003/Site3

Comment: I see, i can think of two different ways to achive this: 
1. create a website foreach virtual directory and add correct binding with specific port.
2. use url rewrite rules to make sure the sites are accessed by the right port.

Is there a reason why you are using virtual directories instead of websites? If not, I would create websites instead and go for the first solution.

Comment: Yes, the virtual directories was recommended by the client. thats why I used the  virtual directories under Default Web Site. So, we can't use the first method.

second, the url rewrite, which is only used to divert the from url to another. But It will not help us for this situation. Sorry for my language, what i want to achieve is to restrict access of a site to a single port. in current situation, multiple sites can be access from a single port.